# Unable to hide rows based on blanks cells in a shared protected sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

I am currently working on a shared document and I believe there are no way to protect/unprotected shared documents when using Excel 2016. When my document are protected I am not able to hide rows based on the value of a specific cells, are there any way for me to allow the macro to run in protected mode?

```
Sub HideBlanks()
Dim rngBlnk As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set rngBlnk = Range("A6:B10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rngBlnk Is Nothing Then
Debug.Print rngBlnk.Address()
rngBlnk.EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You will need to unprotect sheet

Comment: I don't believe that is possible when the document is shared.

Comment: https://analysistabs.com/vba-code/workbook/m/unprotectsharing/

Comment: Are there anyway to lock cells so other user can't modify or change the layout/formulas when using `ActiveWorkbook.ProtectSharing` `ActiveWorkbook.UnprotectSharing` ?